# What is the advanced-trading tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking at tags and saw [advanced-trading](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-trading). What is this tag for? How is it different than [trading](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trading)?  What should the tag-wiki say?  Should we keep it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the advanced-trading tag is redundant with other tags that specifically identify the practice and should be removed.

For example, a short-selling questions was tagged advanced-trading.  I think it should have the tag short-selling and not the tag advanced-trading.

Comment: but.. but.. this is *advanced* trading!